# startsWith method show Underscore in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

```
List days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]

List weekend =  days.findAll { it.startsWith('S')}
println days
println weekend
```

Among them, the startswith method displays an underline in eclipse.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What do you mean by "underscore" or "underline"? Does it indicate an error or
warning? What is the error or warning? It's hard to believe, that an IDE would
tag something as erroneous and then be silent about the why (sort of a bug, of
course).

Comment: Eclipse's intellisense doesn't know the type of `it` in this context, so it can't promise that `startsWith()` is a valid method in that code. If it runs, you're fine. This happens often with i.e. Selenium when I code. Someone better at the inner workings of Eclipse's language parsing could give more details.

Comment: @ou_ryperd That's Groovy. It's not Eclipse, it's the Groovy plugin. Where will the underline displayed? In the Groovy editor? In the output in the _Console_ view? Permanently or only on hover a specific text? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: @howlger I assume this is what OP is talking about https://pasteboard.co/KgqvIeI.png

Comment: If you define the list days with type "def" or "List<String>" then type inference will determine "it" is of type java.lang.String and "startsWith" is a known method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes: it.startsWith(**"S"**)